# How to format a String to display on multiple Lines

Tags: c#, html, string

Here i have a message string that displays the content of an email. I would like the From, The subject and the body to all display on a new line.

Could someone please advise on how this is done. Below is what i'm trying but its all still on one line.

I thought enviroment.newline would work, i still think it will but maby im doing it wrong?

```
MessageString = "From: " + message.Headers.From.Address + Environment.NewLine + "Subject: " + message.Headers.Subject + Environment.NewLine + "Body: " + messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body);
```

> ---

if you could also show me how to write code over multiple lines and still have it function that would be awesome too???????

> ---

Comment: Is that not for Java? yup just tried it, i thinks that's for java :( but thanks for the try :)

Comment: Where is that string presented? In log? On webpage?

Comment: @Pomster "\n" is an escape character it is not language specific

Comment: @Pomster Didn't `Environment.NewLine` work for you ?

Comment: Enviroment.NewLine, "\n" and "\r\n" all have not worked and i have tryed them. The only one that worked was <br /> but that wont work outside of web i dont think. so i can move on :) but did not learn anything. But i do think enviroment.newline will work outside of web maby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If email is in html format then try `<br />`

Comment: Yes this works, but i can help but feel its not the right way to do things. What happens when i'm not displaying onto a webpage how do i new line a string?

Comment: As you did - Environment.NewLine. However, html is not sensitive for any newlines, whitespace, etc. and you have to use special tags to force newline.

Comment: Thanks this was what i needed to know :D could you let me know how to code over multiple lines??? in VB its just _ and then start on the new line C# i'm unsure. I don't want a huge line of code neat code is the way:)

Comment: Just add enter. C# waits for semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `Literal` control with `Mode` set to `PassThrough`, and then use `<br />` for a line break. Literals (and I guess also labels) HTML-encode their content, so a `<br />` is not rendered as a line break by default.

However, be careful: You have to avoid XSS attacks on your own this way! The [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) method is useful therefor.